# if making a .ogg file, do you make it a .ogg file or put it in a file

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

when i was making my resource pack (not avalible to download), i was making the cat music disc make it sound like me. so i ask the question. do i make a file named cat and put cat.ogg in it or so i put the .ogg file in the sounds folder alone? if it should be named something else please tell me

-kind regards, quicker egg

Comment: yep, another question...  ABOUT MINECRAFT FILES!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're unsure where to put resource pack files, you can get a complete default Minecraft texture pack by going to `%appdata%\.minecraft\versions\<latest-version>` and opening the `.jar` file with an archiver (e.g. 7zip, WinRAR etc.). In there, there's an `assets` folder that contains all the built in Minecraft textures and sounds.

Find whichever sound file represents Cat, and make sure to put yours in the exact same place